# What is the usage of 'queryset' attribute of the Django 'CreateView'?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I was wondering what is the usage of 'queryset' attribute of the Django 'CreateView'? The official documentation was not satisfying the question and google isn't helpful enough! I am quite skeptic whether anything obvious is missing from my eyes. Thanks.

Comment: It has no use, this is simply one of the artifacts of the fact that it uses the `SingleObjectMixin`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you can actually specify the queryset instead of the model since the view falls back to getting the model class from the queryset if neither the form nor the model is specified. Agreed that it is not very useful though.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: And I was wondering online for hours and hours to find the functionality of that attribute!! Thanks!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: ah yes, but still I think it might be better to make a *simpler* mixin that then is used by the `SingleObjectMixin` and the `CreateView`, such that it does not define a `queryset`, etc. since this looks more like "noise": it is odd to specify a `queryset` for a createview and not a `model`. But you are right. It uses `self.get_queryset().model` in a `ModelFormMixin`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That's very interesting concept! I have to try that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wish there were some documentation which would indicate the usages and importance of such attributes!

Comment: @Mohammad you can explore from these two links [Built-in class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) and [Built-in class-based views API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/). Personally though I prefer directly looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/views/generic).

Comment: One use case for overriding the queryset is if you do not want to do a lookup in the entire table, but only for certain items in the table: `queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field=True)`.